# First use of $K$ in notation for continued fractions

Tags: notation

I will be giving a lecture soon (on Friday) about continued fractions.  One of the historical compressed notations for continued fractions uses $K$ (from the German word for continued fraction):
$$
a_1 + \underset{k=2}{\overset{\infty}{\sf K}} \frac{1}{a_k} = 
a_1 + \cfrac{1}{a_2 + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + \cfrac{1}{a_4 + \cfrac{1}{{\ddots}}}}}.
$$
This usage is analogous to $\sum$ for sums and $\prod$ for products.

In many places, including the Wikipedia page on continued fractions, the $K$-notation is attributed to Gauss. My question: what is the first paper in which Gauss used this notation, or in fact *any* paper where he used it? I found a couple of papers by Gauss involving continued fractions and in none of them is the $K$-notation used.

In 2017 the same question was asked by someone else [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280938/reference-in-the-literature-for-the-first-use-of-the-k-notation-continued-fract), and that OP had gone through (quickly) all papers by Gauss that appeared related to continued fractions without seeing the  $K$-notation in them. That question has not yet received an  answer. I hope by posting this on a site more focused on the history of (science and) math it may lead to a good answer to this historical question on notation, whether or not it was really due to Gauss.

Comment: [Widz](https://www.mff.cuni.cz/veda/konference/wds/proc/pdf09/WDS09_131_m8_Widz.pdf) claims he used it in 1813 specifically, no reference. It is not in [*Disquisitiones Generales*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_uDMAAAAAQAAJ/page/n135/mode/2up). Did you look in *Mathematisches Tagebuch*? That's one place I can think of if he did not use it "officially".